# How can I force Microsoft Teams to refresh the list of upcoming meetings?

Tags: video-conference, refresh, ms-teams

I use Microsoft Teams on iPad and noticed that the list of upcoming meetings is often outdated.

[image: Microsoft Teams app with the left sidebar of meetings list visible]

How can I force Microsoft Teams to refresh the list of upcoming meetings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to force force Microsoft Teams to refresh the list of upcoming meetings. You just need to pray it refreshes fast enough so that you can join your meetings in time.